# Linq query to find the nth highest value in each group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a group of students with `Name`s and `Mark`s.
I want to return a list containing the `Name` of student and its *nth highest marks*
where `n = 3` in my case.

```
var list = await _studentsDbContext
  .MarksTable
  .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
  .Select(g => new PercentileEntry
      {
          StudentName = g.Key,
          Percentile = g
             .OrderByDescending(g => g.Marks)
             .Take(3)
             .Skip(2)
             .FirstOrDefault()
             .Marks
      })
  .ToListAsync();
```

I tried writing the above query but it **gives exception**

> System.Collections.Generic.List cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`.

Is there a way to write a linq query for that?

Comment: Take(3) Take the top 3 elements of the group. 
Skip(2) Skip the first 2 elements that are taken
We will be left with the 3rd element in the order that will be the third highest element

Comment: Linq questions benefit from providing the schema for the associated records or at least a JSON example of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing an alias in the same scope, I actually expect a different error message in this case, but change the *inner* `g` to something else (not already in use) in the orderby statement:
`.OrderByDescending(m => m.Marks)`

```
var list = await _studentsDbContext
  .MarksTable
  .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
  .Select(g => new PercentileEntry
      {
          StudentName = g.Key,
          Percentile = g
             .OrderByDescending(m => m.Marks)
             // This doesn't really optimise anything, so leave it out.
             //.Take(3)
             .Skip(2)
             .FirstOrDefault()
             .Marks
      })
  .ToListAsync();
```

There is no need to *Take(3)* in this case at all, not unless you were going to *change* the order or your database has some non-standard query mechanics.

This should prepare the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT [m].[Name] AS [StudentName], (
    SELECT [m0].[Marks]
    FROM [MarksTable] AS [m0]
    WHERE ([m].[Name] = [m0].[Name]) OR (([m].[Name] IS NULL) AND ([m0].[Name] IS NULL))
    ORDER BY [m0].[Marks] DESC
    OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS [Percentile]
FROM [MarksTable] AS [m]
GROUP BY [m].[Name]
```

If you leave the `.Take(3)` in, the SQL is a bit more complicated, but is logically the similar:

```sql
SELECT [m].[Name] AS [StudentName], (
    SELECT [t].[Marks]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP(3) [m0].[Id], [m0].[Marks], [m0].[Name], [m0].[Subject]
        FROM [MarksTable] AS [m0]
        WHERE ([m].[Name] = [m0].[Name]) OR (([m].[Name] IS NULL) AND ([m0].[Name] IS NULL))
        ORDER BY [m0].[Marks] DESC
    ) AS [t]
    ORDER BY [t].[Marks] DESC
    OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS [Percentile]
FROM [MarksTable] AS [m]
GROUP BY [m].[Name]
```

- Both of these queries produce the same execution plans because the `TOP(3)` is made redundant by `OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`

You can explore this in the following fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1HoVWq

---

### Update: `'GroupByShaperExpression: .OrderByDescending(m => m.marks)' could not be translated`

If you experience exceptions like this, then it indicates that there is something else *exotic* about your `PercentileEntry` class, could be something as simple as not having a default constructor. I can't be specific about the causes or solutions to this without having more knowledge  of the schema, but there are two geralised options to solve this

1. Use anonymous types to extract the results from the query, then once the filtered and parsed data is in memory, then you can convert it to the required type

   ```
    var rawlist = await _studentsDbContext
            .MarksTable
            .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
            .Select(g => new // removed formal type definition 
             {
                 StudentName = g.Key,
                 Percentile = g
                 .OrderByDescending(m => m.Marks)
                 .Skip(2)
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 .Marks
             })
              .ToListAsync();

    // convert to PercentileEntry if you really need to
    var list = rawlist.Select(x => new PercentileEntry
          {
              StudentName = x.StudentName,
              Percentile = x.Percentile 
          }).ToList();
   ```
2. As recommended by the Exception message, you can move all, or most of this logic into the *client-side*, which is almost always guaranteed to work, but is usually the *worst* advice and if done incorrectly can be incredibly inefficient. Take the following, we can load the entire list of marks into memory, then it's just standard LINQ to objects.

   ```
    var list = (await _studentsDbContext.MarksTable.ToListAsync())
      .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
      .Select(g => new PercentileEntry
          {
              StudentName = g.Key,
              Percentile = g
                 .OrderByDescending(m => m.Marks)
                 .Skip(2)
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 .Marks
          })
      .ToList();
   ```

##### A Note about `.Take()` and `.Skip()`

If your data is already in memory, so this is *not* a LINQ-to-Entities or SQL scenario, so if we are already in the client context...

Then the *Take* in this chain `.Take(3).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()` is still redundant. `.Skip(2)` skips past the first 2 elements, then `.FirstOrDefault()` terminates the expression, so the `.Take(3)` never really gets evaluated.

- `.Take()` and `.Skip()` do not run to completion before the next element is returned, not like *OrderBy* that is effectively fully executed before the records are *yielded* to the next `IEnumerable` statement. `.Take()` and `.Skip()` are non-blocking processes that evaluate and *yield* to all the chained `IEnumerable` operations before the *next* item is evaluated:

  1. *Move Next* => *First Item*
  2. `.Take(3)` => `yield` (1 returned)
  3. `.Skip(2)` => `continue;` (1 skipped)
  4. *Move Next* => *Second Item*
  5. `.Take(3)` => `yield` (2 returned)
  6. `.Skip(2)` => `continue;` (2 skipped)
  7. *Move Next* => *Third Item*
  8. `.Take(3)` => `yield` (2 returned)
  9. `.Skip(2)` => `yield` (2 have already skipped)
  10. `.FirstOrDefault()` => `return` (Breaks on the first record)

In that chain, we never get the the point where `.Take()` gets to influence the outcome of the expression, If there was another item, then it would `break;` the current loop, but not fully return like `FirstOrDefault()` does.

- Interestingly, if you had used `.Single()` then it would have had a chance to be evaluated, but the final outcome would be the same. This is because `.Single()` actually performs a `.Take(2)` and throws an exception if there is a second record... just a fun fact ;)

Comment: This gives
The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
.OrderByDescending(m => m.marks)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.]

Comment: You'll need to provide the actual classes for me to assist further, please see my updated post with strategies to work around your localised issue.